# Issue with Memcached with session storing

Tags: php, session, memcached

Today i had to move to **MemcacheD** because of php7* .ver

after installing Memcached pecl for php7 i tried to store my session to Memcached but i saw it will take too much longer than default session store ( files )

**Page load without Sess. Memcached < 200 ms**

**Page load with Sess. Memcached ABOVE 5 sec**

And the problem is only with session ! i tried to store other datas in memcached and retrieved them asap without any lag or so.

My MemcacheD setting is:

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1024"
CACHESIZE="512"
OPTIONS="-l 127.0.0.1"
```

And my Pecl PHP Memcached Setting ( shown in phpinfo too ) is:

```
extension=memcached.so

session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path="localhost:11211"

[memcached]
memcached.sess_locking = On
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min = 1000;
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max = 2000;
memcached.sess_lock_retries = 10;
memcached.sess_lock_expire = 0;
memcached.sess_prefix = "memc.sess.key."
memcached.sess_persistent = Off
memcached.sess_consistent_hash = On
memcached.sess_remove_failed)
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers = Off
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas = 0
memcached.sess_binary_protocol = On
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read = Off
memcached.sess_connect_timeout = 1000
memcached.sess_sasl_username = NULL
memcached.sess_sasl_password = NULL
memcached.compression_type = "fastlz"
memcached.compression_factor = "1.3"
memcached.compression_threshold = 2000
memcached.serializer = "igbinary"
memcached.store_retry_count = 2
memcached.default_consistent_hash = Off
memcached.default_binary_protocol = Off
memcached.default_connect_timeout = 0
```

**+** I checked with session_write_close() and the result was the same so i assume its not session lock problem

And the php is running with FPM unix socket if it is relevant

regards

Comment: Try to set `session.save_path="unix://run/memcached/memcached.sock"` like this if php is running with FPM unix socket. If still not work then try `session.save_path="/run/memcached/memcached.sock"`. Restart FPM in both cases.

Comment: @DileepKumar Tnx i tried both. first one not working but second one work fine and connected to memcached server but sill problem with session exist ! if i store even 1 small data into session when using memcache page load will be higher than 5 sec again its really really weird ! i dont know its because of the problem with memcached pecl compactibility with php 7 or what cause this , im scared to use it at all for other datas maybe in future i get same problem with other datas too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was **fixed** by updating libmemcached **1.0.16** to **1.0.18** manually since the yum repos only had 1.0.16

With update now session store use memcached asap without any delay.

regards